# python (nontype comparison with int)

Tags: python

Actually i m trying to make binary search tree but there a nonetype in self.value ..so there is an error saying < cannot be used with int and none type.please help me regarding this .Thanks for the help ..I m really stuck with it.............................................................................................................................................................

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self,initval=None):
        self.value=initval
        if self.value:
            self.left=Tree()
            self.right=Tree()
        else :
            self.left=None
            self.right=None

        return


    def isempty(self):
        return (self.value==None)

    def isleaf(self):
        return (self.left.isempty() and self.right.isempty())

    # convert a leaf node to an empty node
    def makeempty(self):
        self.value=None
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

        return

    def copyright(self):
        self.value=self.right.value
        self.left=self.right.left
        self.right=self.right.right
        return


    def find(self,v):
        if self.isempty():
            return (False)

        if self.value==v:
            return (True)

        if v<self.value:
            return (self.left.find(v))

        if v>self.value:
            return (self.right.find(v))


    def insert(self,v):
        if self.isempty():
            self.value==v
            self.left=Tree()
            self.right=Tree()

        if self.value==v:
            return

        if v < self.value:
            self.left.insert(v)
            return
        if v >self.value:
            self.right.insert(v)
            return


    def maxval(self):
        if self.right.isempty():
            return(self.value)
        else:
            return (self.right.maxval())


    def delete(self,v):
        if self.isempty():
            return
        if v<self.value:
            self.left.delete(v)
        if v>self.value:
            self.right.delete(v)


        if v==self.value:
            if self.isleaf():
                self.makeempty()
            elif self.left.isempty():
                self.copyright()
            else:
                self.value=self.left.maxval()
                self.left.delete(self.left.maxval())
            return

    def inorder(self):
        if self.isempty():
            return([])
        else:
            return (self.left.inorder()+[self.value]+self.right.inorder())


    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.inorder()))

l=Tree(4)
for i in [1,3,2,6,8,55,44]:
    l.insert(i)

print(l)
```

Comment: In your find function, you never ensure that the value is not `None`. And, why would you save a node storing a `None`value on a binary tree? That doesn't feel right, you should just delete that node, and set it's parent <left or rigt> son to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add a condition in the if, to ensure you actually have a left or right node, and you have a value different than None in the actual node. Something like this

```
def find(self,v):
    if self.value is None:
        return False

    if self.value==v:
        return (True)

    if v<self.value and self.left is not None:
        return (self.left.find(v))

    if v>self.value and self.right is not None:
        return (self.right.find(v))

    return False
```

I didn't tested it out, but I think that should work. Hope it helps.

As a side note, you could research on the iterative search in a binary tree, it is more efficient than recursion approach